# jquery mouseover/mouseout issue

Tags: jquery, events

I have this issue where `mouseover` on a `div` (`div.stripPopupTrigger`) fires an AJAX call which gets some data and displays a popup box with that data. However, within that `div` is a `span` that has some text associated with it (see HTML below).

The issue is, when I `mouseover` the `span` and then out of the `span` into the `div`, the AJAX call fires again (kind of expected I guess). I'm looking to stop any triggers from `span` to `div.stripPopupTrigger`. Of course from any parent of `div.stripPopupTrigger` must fire as expected.

```
<div class='stripPopupTrigger cabinet-strip-type ".$type." ' style='background-color:".$color.";'>
<span class='cabinet-results-kw-value' style=''>".sprintf("%01.2f", $power)."</span><br />
  <span class='cabinet-results-kw-kw'>KW</span><br />
  <span class='cabinet-results-kw-name'>".$name."</span>
</div>
```

jQuery looks like below:

```
$('.stripPopupTrigger').live('mouseover', function() {

//some code here

$.ajax({            
  type: 'GET',  
  url: 'kwfinder/getdata',  
  data: 'strip=' + stripName,   
  success: function(data) {
    // some code here
  }
});
```

The `.live('mouseout')` event just adjusts CSS display to none. Hiding the popup box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event instead of mouseover. It should do what you want.